# while running this programe i occured one error as ambigous redirect

Tags: linux, shell

This is my following bash script

```
cat >> $file_name
```

And I receive this kind of error:

> ./l7.sh: line 12: $file_name: ambiguous redirect

### Here are the full code

https://github.com/vats147/public/blob/main/l7.sh

And Why I am getting this error? even my syntax is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into the parameter `file_name` you must assign `$1`, which will pass to the current file as an input parameter.

```
#! /bin/bash

echo -e " Enter file name : \c"
read file_name=$1
if [ -f $file_name ]
then
    if [ -w $file_name ]
    then
        echo " type some text data. to quit press enter "
        #cat > $file_name(single angular bracket use for overwritten)
        #cat >> $file_name(two angular bracket use for appending a text)
        cat >> $file_name
    else
        echo " file not have write permission"      
    fi
else
    echo "file not exist"
fi
```

These are positional arguments of the script.

Executing `./script.sh Hello World` will make

```
$0 = ./script.sh
$1 = Hello
$2 = World
```

Note

If you execute `./script.sh`, `$0` will give output `./script.sh` but if you execute it with bash `script.sh` it will give output `script.sh`.

Comment: Not perfect solution